# express res.cookie not saving cookie with expires or maxAge

Tags: express, cookies, jwt

I've got a REST API where I'm using passport-JWT to auth my apis, and I'm storing the JWT in a cookie. I'm having an issue creating a cookie with res.cookie, I am able to create a cookie using the following:

```
res.cookie('auth_token', token, { httpOnly: true});
```

But if I add either 'expires or maxAge' the cookie isn't created, and I don't get any error messages.

```
res.cookie('auth_token', token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true});
```

I've been going through the documentation and I'm stumped to why its not working. I've also checked my auth just incase the cookie is ignored by browser. Below are my dev dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.15.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"jwt-simple": "^0.5.0",
"mongoose": "^4.4.17",
"morgan": "^1.7.0",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-jwt": "^2.0.0",
"redis": "^2.6.0-2 ",
"socket.io": "^1.4.6"
},
```

Comment: are the server and client clocks synched? It could be that the client's clockl is ahead by more than 900 seconds, which means the cookie expired before being set.

Comment: I dont think it is that, Ive uploaded my app to heroku and it still does the same thing.